# Update column A if exist 'text in column B

Tags: sql, sql-update

I want to change a columns record if in other column exist the exact text.

For example:

In table: videos I have 100 records with 3 columns

id, url, category

I want to change the url on each record if exist the text 'trailer' in category column

Is there an option to run any code in SQL to change it automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the WHERE condition

```
UPDATE table_name
SET url = new_url
WHERE category LIKE '%trailer%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE tablename
set url = 'some url'
where CHARINDEX(category, ‘trailer’) > 0
```

I would suggest not to use like %text% as its becomes slow and doesnt take indexes into accouny.

Comment: Thank you, I have run this: 

UPDATE videos
set url = 'https://mylink.com'
where CHARINDEX(category, ‘trailer’) > 0

but show me this error: #1305 - FUNCTION fmsecrmy_movie.CHARINDEX does not exist

Comment: which database are u running. this is for sql server